# SQL nested aggregate wage by quarter

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, nested, aggregate-functions

I am trying to aggregate wages for worker for 8 quarters.  As columns, have

```
employee id
quarter (1 digit int)
year (4 digit int)
quarterly_wage
year_quarter (string i created from quarter and year)
```

I would like to have each row with

```
employee id, year_quarter, 8 quarters of wages
```

e.g.,
2 employees, one starts in 2010 quarter 1 and the second starts in 2010 quarter 4.  data is from 2010Q1 to 2014Q4.

```
Employ1 2010Q1 SumOfWages2010Q1_2012Q4
Employ1 2010Q2 SumOfWages2012Q2_2013Q1
Employ1 2010Q3 SumOfWages2012Q2_2013Q2
Employ1 2010Q4 SumOfWages2012Q2_2013Q3
Employ2 2010Q4 SumOfWages2010Q4_2012Q3
etc...
```

this will be for 15 years, 1000 employees.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have full data for all employees (that is, no gaps), you can do:

```
select empid, year, quarter, quarterly_wage
       sum(quarterly_wage) over (partition by emp_id
                                 order by year, quarter
                                 rows between current row and 7 following
                                ) as wages_8quarters
from t;
```

Comment: oh my, i went to sleep and found an answer similar... thank you for a better solution!

Comment: I want to create a boolean column to show that a person has worked with the same employer for at least two consecutive quarters, ideally >=3.  I have joined employers w/ "people" employee ID.  I have ordered the join by employee ID & YearQuarter.  I have other variables that i will retain in query.  The employee could have worked with multiple employers in a quarter or multiple quarters.  not concerned about those cases.